# Navigation Controller does not show up in TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have 3 Views in my app: Test, Summary and Details

I have a Tab Bar which shows Summary Table View. Clicking Table View shows Details view.

Now, on test page, at the end, I am showing Summary Table view. But doing so, navigation bar does not show up. It shows when I go to Summary page by clicking Tab Bar, but not from Quiz page.

I am using below code to display Summary TableView from Quiz view:

[self.navigationController pushviewController:Summary animated:YES];

It shows Table View fine, but no Navigation Bar.

How do I show Navigation bar?

I have tried added it thru XIB but it wont show.

Thanks!

Comment: go through your code again and check if you have set the navigation bar hidden property in IB or code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked in code and IB but there is no hidden property for navigation bar. Besides, navigation bar shows fine when we go to Summary page from Tab bar.

Comment: Is it possible that navigation bar was getting overlapped by the table view? If yes, how to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this line of code to your viewDidLoad method:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

This will unhide the navigation bar.